# Prevent digits to change from English to Arabic on Locale updated android

Tags: android, locale

I'm providing Arabic support for the already-completed app. On changing the app language to Arabic, numbers are displaying with Arabic digits for the XML strings.

But my problem is on executing the following code

```
getString(R.string.value, ++value);
```

**values**

```
<string name="value">Value : %d</string>
```

**values-ar**

```
<string name="value">%d :القيمة </string>
```

with English, it is working fine.

```
Value: 1
```

On changing the language to Arabic (Appearing in Arabic). It must be in English (0-9)

```
Value : (Number in Arabic)
```

Please provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: I don't understand what happened, in Arabic locale, the number is shown in English and you want to be Arabic? Or conversely, the number is shown in Arabic while it must be English.

Comment: I  want to show only English numbers instead of Arabic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the locale of the number using `String.format` to always be shown in English:

```
String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, getString(R.string.value), ++value)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution, but I have to update in the overall app. is any other way for this?

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, but maybe unusual to achieve! I had the same problem but adversely. So, I used a font in my app that was replacing Latin digits with Persian digits. You can edit a font with fontforge. But I think handling this situation programmatically like the above answer takes lower effort.

Answer (score 0):

Although it takes a long time to ask this question (7 months), it may be useful for others. I did this  and my problem was solved.

First I created a Locale variable:

```
val englishLocale = Locale("en")
```

Then I used this variable in the required functions:

For example for date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", englishLocale)
```

Or to display elapsed time in milliseconds in normal format:

```
String.format(englishLocale, "%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, seconds % 60)
```